# Ethernet card cannot be detected during Ubuntu server 18.04.05 installation

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, ethernet

I'm trying to set up ubuntu 18.04 server on my desktop, but I was stuck, because the installer couldn't find the network card.

I also tried to use hwe mode, but I still have the same problem.

I cannot manually install the driver after the server is installed, because compiling from the source requires several packages that should be installed during the installation when the network is availiable.

The ethernet card comes with the motherboard and here is its spec:
Model:

- Asus PRIME B560M-K
- Chipset: B560
- Ethernet: Intel I219-V
- Dual boot: no (clean install, ubuntu only)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Is Ubuntu 18.04 an absolute requirement? If you can use Ubuntu 20.04.2 (or newer) with HWE, then the necessary drivers are baked into the kernel.

Comment: are you dual booting with Windows? please [edit] your question rather than add to the comment chain.

Comment: Dear matigo. Yes, 20.04 can be installed without this problem. However, many packages I'm going to use are not fully compatible with it, that's why I have to downgrade to 18.04.